# Why are images crashing when deployed on Vercel in React App?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, vercel

The images that I import and use in my react app crashes when deployed, on Vercel.

I am importing images from "Images" folder in src folder giving it relative path like this:

```
import upload from '../../../images/upload.svg';
```

And using it in JSX like this:

```
<img style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }} src={upload} alt="Upload" />
<p className="textMed">Upload File Here</p>
<p>Supported formats : JPG, JPEG, PNG</p>
```

It is working perfectly fine on Localhost but crashed when it is deployed on Server.

[image]

What is the problem here, is it server issue or SVG type issue.

Comment: I don't think this is a server issue or an SVG type issue. I think you need to check the import and confirm whether the image is being uploaded to the same path after deployment or not.

Comment: @hassansuhaib if i inspect over the src of img tag and follow the link  "./static/media/upload.98a0f211a5743411b2bae2cf69f00aa5.svg" with base url, it shows the image. So i guess the path on deployed app works